# Rails 4 view slim-lang wrapping issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, word-wrap, slim-lang

I have been working with [Slim lang](http://slim-lang.com/index.html) for a short amount of time now on a Rails 4 application I am constructing and one issue that has been puzzling me is wrapping.  As you can see from the attached code snippet below the input text line goes on forever and a day.

No matter what I try I can not seem to get it to span multiple lines.  I realize I may be bumping up to a bad a practice here trying to make my code more readable but I want to reach out to fellow engineers to confirm.

```
form[id="register-frm" data-parsley-validate]
  div[class="row"]
    div[class="large-12 large-centered columns"]
      label[for="age_verify"]
        input[type="checkbox" id="register-age-verify" parsley-group="age-verify" required]
        | Are you 18 at least years old?
  div[class="row"]
    div[class="large-12 large-centered columns"]
      div[class="email-field"]
        input[type="email" id="register-email" class="large" parsley-type="email" parsley-required-message="Email required!" parsley-type-email-message="Valid email format name@yourmail.com required!" placeholder="name@yourmail.com" required]
  div[class="row"]
    div[class="large-12 large-centered columns"]
      input[type="button" id="register-btn" class="button button-1 expand radius" value="Register Now"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I'd do it:

```
input[type="email" 
      id="register-email" 
      class="large" 
      parsley-type="email" 
      parsley-required-message="Email required!" 
      parsley-type-email-message="Valid email format name@yourmail.com required!" 
      placeholder="name@yourmail.com" required]
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. I appreciate it.  Learned something new today!